# Add opacity to chromakey shader in aframe

Tags: three.js, shader, aframe, blending

I'm using [this shader](https://github.com/nikolaiwarner/aframe-chromakey-material/blob/master/README.md) to chromakey a video. I would like to **add opacity** to the same video. I've been trying to add the opacity component to the shader but something more must be missing (don't know what).

I've added opacity in the schema:

```
opacity: {type: 'number', is: 'uniform', default: 0.5}
```

And in the update function:

```
this.material.uniforms.opacity = data.opacity
```

Here's all the shader code:

```
AFRAME.registerShader('chromakey', {
  schema: {
    src: {type: 'map'},
    color: {default: {x: 0.1, y: 0.9, z: 0.2}, type: 'vec3', is: 'uniform'},
    transparent: {default: true, is: 'uniform'},
    opacity: {type: 'number', is: 'uniform', default: 0.5}
  },

  init: function (data) {
    var videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(data.src)
    videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: {
        color: {
          type: 'c',
          value: data.color
        },
        texture: {
          type: 't',
          value: videoTexture
        }
      },
      vertexShader: this.vertexShader,
      fragmentShader: this.fragmentShader
    })
  },

  update: function (data) {
    this.material.color = data.color
    this.material.src = data.src
    this.material.transparent = data.transparent
    this.material.uniforms.opacity = data.opacity
  },

  vertexShader: [
    'varying vec2 vUv;',
    'void main(void)',
    '{',
    'vUv = uv;',
    'vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );',
    'gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;',
    '}'
  ].join('\n'),

  fragmentShader: [
    'uniform sampler2D texture;',
    'uniform vec3 color;',
    'varying vec2 vUv;',
    'void main(void)',
    '{',
    'vec3 tColor = texture2D( texture, vUv ).rgb;',
    'float a = (length(tColor - color) - 0.5) * 7.0;',
    'gl_FragColor = vec4(tColor, a);',
    '}'
  ].join('\n')


})
```

Comment: what happens if you just set `a = 0.3`?

Comment: I presume you're referring to the 'a' in the fragmentshader. If so, then I get opacity but lose the chromakey effect.

Comment: I just wanted to see if setting a constant alpha will produce some opacity or not. Since you do get opacity then the issue is with the formula you use for `a`. What are the limits of that function (i.e. what is the possible min value and what is the possible max value) because it should be close to [0,1]. If you get negative values or values much above 1 the driver is clamping them so you are loosing the effect you want most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update the value of the uniform (`function update`), the you have to set the `value` property and you have to set the notification, that the uniforms of the material needs to be updated (`needsUpdate`):

```
 this.material.uniforms.opacity.value = data.opacity
 this.material.needsUpdate = true
```

Further you have to add the uniform `opacity` to the fragment shader. See the following fragment shader which multiplies the `opacity` uniform to the alpha channel:

```
uniform float     opacity;
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform vec3      color;
varying vec2      vUv;

void main(void)
{
    vec3 tColor = texture2D( texture, vUv ).rgb;
    float a = (length(tColor - color) - 0.5) * 7.0;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(tColor, a * opacity);
}
```

Note, if `opacity` is set to 0.0, the output will disappear completely.

Comment: I did the changes you've mentioned and the output is no visible video. And opacity is set to 0.5.

Comment: UPDATE: I did manage to get some results by manually adding the opacity value to 0.2, i.e. in the fragment shader: `gl_FragColor = vec4(tColor, a * 0.2);`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add an opacity uniform to the shader in order for it to support what you want.

Try the following code (I haven't tested it) and see if it behaves how you want

```
fragmentShader: [
    'uniform sampler2D texture;',
    'uniform vec3 color;',
    'uniform float opacity;', // add the uniform to the shader
    'varying vec2 vUv;',
    'void main(void)',
    '{',
        'vec3 tColor = texture2D( texture, vUv ).rgb;',
        'float a = (length(tColor - color) - 0.5) * 7.0;',
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(tColor, a*opacity);', // add the opacity multiplier to the alpha channel
    '}'
].join('\n')
```

Comment: The video just disappears completely.